# Express/Passport deserializeUser not called, req.session.passport undefined

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I've got an Express server using Passport for auth and a React frontend.

When I post a login request, it works; req.session console logs as:

```js
 cookie: 
   { path: '/',
 _expires: 2018-02-25T01:06:21.555Z,
 originalMaxAge: 14400000,
 httpOnly: true,
 secure: false },
 passport: { user: 'test' }
```

('test' is in fact the username I'm using). For now I'm just trying to debug this using a test route and a simple get request:

```js
fetch('/api/auth/test', { credentials: 'include' })
```

I console log req.session and passport is gone:

```js
 cookie: 
   { path: '/',
 _expires: 2018-02-25T01:06:26.596Z,
 originalMaxAge: 14400000,
 httpOnly: true,
 secure: false }
```

Here's my Passport code:

In my route:

```js
authRoutes.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.json({ message: info }); }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.json({ message: 'ok', user: user.username });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

local.js:

```js
const options = {};

init();

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) => {
    User.findByUsername(username)
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, 'badUser');
        }
        if (!authHelpers.comparePass(password, user.password)) {
          return done(null, false, 'badPw');
        }
        return done(null, user);
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
  })
);
```

I've been working on this for hours and can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?